# CMDeviceMotion issues with multiplyByInverseOfAttitude

Tags: iphone, core-motion

I am having my first play around with Core Motion and have struck an issue and I can't work out what is going on. I am sure it is going to be a simple issue. Here is some code:

.h file

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import <CoreMotion/CoreMotion.h>

@interface TempVC : UIViewController {
CMMotionManager *motionManager;
CMAttitude *referenceAttitude;
CMAttitude *attitude;
}
- (void)updateData;
@end
```

.m file

```
#import "TempVC.h"
#define DEGREES(radians) (radians / M_PI * 180.0)
@implementation TempVC

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
[super viewDidLoad];
self.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor brownColor];

motionManager = [[CMMotionManager alloc] init]; 
referenceAttitude = nil;

CMDeviceMotion *dm = motionManager.deviceMotion;
attitude = dm.attitude;
referenceAttitude = [attitude retain];

motionManager.deviceMotionUpdateInterval = 0.1;
[motionManager startDeviceMotionUpdates];

[NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:0.1 target:self selector:@selector(updateData) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];

}

- (void)updateData
{
attitude = motionManager.deviceMotion.attitude;
[attitude multiplyByInverseOfAttitude:referenceAttitude];
NSLog(@"\n Roll: %.0f\n Pitch: %.0f\n Yaw: %.0f",DEGREES(attitude.roll), DEGREES(attitude.pitch), DEGREES(attitude.yaw));
}
```

This code will crash with no real indication of what goes wrong. If I comment out

```
[attitude multiplyByInverseOfAttitude:referenceAttitude];
```

Everything works fine??? Have I implemented the reference wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You access CMMotionManager's deviceMotion property before starting updates. There you store your referenceAttitude which will still be nil at that time. When updateData is called a few millis later `[attitude multiplyByInverseOfAttitude:referenceAttitude];` will fail.

Try instead to set the referenceAttitude on the first call of updateData and it should work.

Comment: I took your advice and added if (referenceAttitude == nil) { referenceAttitude = [attitude retain]; } and removed it from viewDidLoad but it made no difference???? its strange, I am sure this code should work. Thanks for the try :)

Comment: Is there any other place where referenceAttitude is used? Try setting a breakpoint in updateData to ivnestigate if it is the 1st, 2nd or n-th call. Maybe CMAttitude doesn't like it to be multplied with itself? Try putting the multiplyBIOA into else block of if (referenceAttitude == nil)